# Running a script as sudo wihout terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, script

I'm working on a tool for a client which needs to be run as sudo (I found out later that it doesn't work without sudo as I've never worked on a Mac before). I have the binary ready, and I wrote a shell script to call that binary as sudo.

However, the problem is that the shell script isn't able to find the binary, and also it outputs the wrong path with `pwd`. The location of the binary isn't fixed and it could be placed anywhere, so I cannot hardcode the path into the shell script.

To elaborate a little on the pwd outputting wrong path: the script was placed in a location whose path is `/Volumes/MySSD/MiscFiles/` and the output of `pwd` through the shell script was `/User/<my client's username>`.

Another important constraint is that my client cannot operate a terminal, so for him when he double clicks on the executable it starts. But I need this to run as sudo otherwise it doesn't work.

So, my question is, is there a way to make it so that when I double click the binary from the file explorer (I think it is called Finder in Mac), it should run as sudo.

Or,is there something wrong I'm doing in my shell script?

this is my shell script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# sudo ./actiontool #actiontool is the binary, and this command didn't work, it gave a no such file or directory error
# echo $(pwd) #this echoed the wrong path
sudo .$(pwd)/actiontool #also didnt work as $(pwd) outputs the wrong path
```

Comment: You have too many variables here. Why do you need a shell script. If the executable couild be anywhere how does the user know how to call it? I suspect the end result is that you need to make it an app. ALso what does it need sudo for - macOS is a Unix so should behave as other Unices

Comment: I initially wasn't using a shell script. The tool transfers files over http, and it was giving permission errors without sudo. So I wrote a shell script so that my client can simply double click on the shell script from Finder and then it'll open the terminal, ask for the password and the script will work normally. All this because my client cannot operate a terminal, no other reason

Comment: @mmmmmm MacOS is quite restrictive with what you can do as a non-root user.

Comment: transfer files giving permission errors needing sudo means you have a big security issue. You should not be writing to areas that need sudo. Where exactly are they being transferred to?

Comment: @RishiC Permission errors when transferring files sound more like you want to use parts of the filesystem you should not be using as a normal user.  Care to provide more details?

Comment: They are being transferred to a Raspberry Pi, whose recieving side code also I've written, so I know there's no threat there due it being a transfer over a local network. As for the location of the files being transferred, they can be anywhere a regular user can access i.e Desktop, Documents, external drive etc. @mmmmmm

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the files being accessed can be stored anywhere a normal user can easily access i.e Documents, Desktop etc

Comment: OK two issues if they are being transferred to a Pi why do they need to be stored on the Mac. Second to save in Documents you need extra permissions and sudo is not they way to do this/

Comment: This should _not_ require sudo access.  I think you have an X-Y problem here.  Consider opening a new question asking how to do this - it might turn out to be very simple.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds silly, I'm new to Mac, can you elaborate a little on the X-Y problem so I can ask a proper question about it? @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: The XY problem is a communication problem encountered in help desk and similar situations in which the person asking for help obscures the real issue, X, because instead of asking directly about issue X, they ask how to solve a secondary issue, Y, which they believe will allow them to resolve issue X. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: So what we are asking is tart with the overal function you are trying to do ie here looks like whow do I erite an app than transfers data from an external source to a raspberry PI. For example it is not clear why the data is saved to a mac at all

Comment: The tool performs backups of the mac, which is irrelevant here for the most part, as the functionality has been tested by me on linux systems as well as windows. Mac is a problem because it is giving me permission errora

Comment: Mac has far more complex perms than nix or win. That's still the 'X' you need to clarify.

Comment: MacOS has rsync. You really need a good reason for reinventing another wheel.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about rsync. Thank you so much @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. So here I can simply write a script that will call rsync (based on inputs so that the user can select which files/folders he wants to backup) right?

Answer (score 1):

The full path of the shell script including its name is in `$0`. You can extract the path by using `${0%/*}`.

This doesn't solve other issues though:

- Double-clicking the script will open Terminal which might confuse the user
- `sudo` will only work as expected if the user is an Administrator (or if you changed `/etc/sudoers` but I assume you didn't)
- They still need to enter their password in the Terminal window.

PS: The probably better way to approach this might be handling any access right issues from within the application.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Automatically opening the terminal isn't a problem as he only needs to enter his password, which I showed him and he is quite comfortable with it